# Swift SKConstraint

Tags: ios, constraints, sknode

Struggling with implementing SKConstraint in my iOS rugby game app.

Basically I create multiple nodes called 'defenders', the number depending on how many that particular level requires. Each node is named defender+number.

Thus if 3 defenders are spawned I have 3 defender nodes called: defender1, defender2, defender3

This is the code I used to spawn the defender node with initial positioning:

```
for defenderNumber in 1 ..< (numberDefenders+1) {
        let defender = Defender(imageNamed: "defender_\(teamShirt)")
        defender.position = CGPoint(x: defenderXposition, y: defenderYposition)
        defender.size = CGSize (width: 50, height: 35)
        defender.zPosition = 2
        defender.name = "defender\(defenderNumber)"
        defenderXposition = defenderXposition + defenderSpacing
        addChild(defender)

        }
```

As part of the game the defenders then chase the attackers in various defensive patterns. However I've noticed that the defenders tend to group together and I want to include a constraint where the defenders keep a minimum distance away from each other.

I thought I would use a SKConstraint such as:

`let range = SKRange(lowerLimit:150, upperLimit:1000)
            let constraint = SKConstraint.distance(range, to:defender)
            defender.constraints = [constraint]`

I tried putting the above constraint code in my defender spawn code but it doesn't seem to have an effect.

Any advice greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

If anyone else is having this issue, I have created a work around - however its horribly clunky and not particularly easy on the coders eye!

The issue with the above I worked out was that as I was adding one defender childNode at a time in an iteration loop, I couldn't constrain that particular defender node to another defender as they did not exist within that loop.

Thus to work around this, after adding each defender node to the game scene I  nestled an node iteration loop inside another. Both iterated through the same set of defender nodes, but I called the second iteration 'next defender' within the first iteration loop. So for each defender brought up in the first loop, all the defenders are brought up in the second, assigned a different node name, and then I linked constraints to all second iteration nodes to the first.

```
    for defenderNumber in 1 ..< (self.numberDefenders+1) {
        enumerateChildNodes(withName: "defender\(defenderNumber)", using: {node, stop in

            let defender = node as! Defender

            for defenderNumber in 1 ..< (self.numberDefenders+1) {
                self.enumerateChildNodes(withName: "defender\(defenderNumber)", using: {node, stop in

                    let nextdefender = node as! Defender
                    let range = SKRange(lowerLimit:50)
                    let constraint = SKConstraint.distance(range, to:nextdefender)
                    defender.constraints = [constraint]
                })

            }
        })

    }
```

This hurts my eyes so much that if anyone has a more elegant way of achieving this I would appreciate it greatly!